# Howto use more than one clip on one page?

Tags: video.js

Hi I am using more than one clips on my site with video.js player. My problem is than, if you click on another clip the first one still runs.

How do I have to set the player only to run the selected clip?

I gave all clips unique IDs but this doesn't solve it.

Any ideas?

Thanks katasun

Answer (score 0):

When starting a video clip, you need to check all other clips and stop them, if running. You could do this in JavaScript like this:

```
playerIDs = ['id1', 'id2'];
var length = playerIDs.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  var myPlayer  = videojs(playerIDs[i]);
  myPlayer.on("play", function() {
    for (var a = 0; a < length; a++) {
        if(playerIDs[i] != playerIDs[a]) {
            var otherPlayer  = videojs(playerIDs[a]);
            otherPlayer.pause();
        }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code and sorry for the late answer. I tried it, but it was not working, I am calling the clips in iframes, maybe this makes it more difficult, however I will continue to find a solution.

Comment: You could provide a JS Fiddle, if you need further help.